# Http requests not working in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-get

I'm so confused right now. I've tried everything and I still cannot get this to work. Basically, I'm trying to get the **HTML** of a website, but it only works on Google. Here's my code:

```js
const HttpClient = {
    get: function(url, callback) {
        var str = '';
        var req = http.get(url, function(response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                callback(str);
            });
        }).on;
        return true
    }
}
HttpClient.get('http://www.google.com/index.html', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

You can see that the URL I am providing is **google.com**. This is the only URL that I have found that actually returns something. Replacing the URL with anything else will make it not return anything.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please add the URLs that didn't work for you?

Comment: I tried youtube and the netflix api, neither worked. @ManasJayanth

Comment: Those apis usually use https. Are you sure you are using node's `https` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the blue 'Run code snippet' button and inspect the error message.

{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: http is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 11
}

You need to make sure you're requiring node's http module.

I was able to successfully make a GET request using your exact code (albeit with a different url) and after requiring the http module.

Updated to use https:

```
const https = require('https')

const HttpClient = {
    get: function(url, callback) {
        var str = '';
        var req = https.get(url, function(response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                callback(str);
            });
        })

        return true
    }
}

HttpClient.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRvwlX3ihRg', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that URL seems to work. Try youtube.com, it didn't work for me. Also, I forgot to include http, but I did declare it.

Comment: YouTube.com uses https, so you'll need to require the https module, see updated answer.

Comment: @Josh facebook.com still doesn't work with this solution